# Put references at the end of the thesis/dissertation

Tags: bibtex, cross-referencing, natbib, thesis

I'm using delft dissertation template from sharelatex.
this template uses chapterbib to put bibliografy at the end of each chapter but i don't want that.
i want my references to be at the end of the thesis.
i edited the style file and removed
`\usepackage{chapterbib}`
and also removed sectionbib from
`\RequirePackage[,numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}`
but still no success.
placed
`\references{dissertation}` in each chapter file but still.
all the references are `??`
anyone please suggest smth.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Comment: the working example is here https://www.sharelatex.com/project/58aef7f5920c877403e3db95

Comment: The `chapterbib` package *lets* you create per-chapter bibliographies, but it doesn't force you to do so. You're entirely free to create a single bibliography, presumably to be placed somewhere near the end of the document. Incidentally, if all your citation call-outs look like `??`, it's an indication that you haven't run BibTeX correctly.

Comment: i know that, i read the documentation of chapterbib. but still cannot achieve what i want. Please take a look at this link, is the template to try  http://sharelatex.com/project/58aef7f5920c877403e3db95

Comment: I consider the template from Delft university not to be very good. Nevermind, following your ink the website asks me to log in. Are you sure we can access your project?

Comment: A minimal working example would be better. Of course, some basic knowledge of LaTeX is needed to create one. On the other hand, basic knowledge is needed to use a template as well. And i think the dissertation guidelines of TU Delft are there for a reason.